# Acf Pro repeater field returns null when call inside foreach

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have a problem with the repeater field in Acf Pro. I want to retrieve fields  inside the foreach but it gives me "null" value.

Can someone help me?

My code:

```
function label_text( $post_id = '' ) {
            while( have_rows('description', $post_id) ): the_row();
                    $description .= get_sub_field('label') . get_sub_field('text');
            endwhile;
    return $description;
}
```

```
foreach ( $query->posts as $id ) {
            $label_text = label_text( $id );
            $logo = get_field('logo', $id);
            $results[ get_the_title( $id ) ] = array(
                'id'           => $id,
                'description'  => $label_text,
                'logo'         => $logo['url'],
                'type'         => get_post_type($id),
        );
}
```

Comment: 3rd Party Plugins ( such as Advanced Custom Fields ) are considered to be Off-Topic here - you may get a faster response from their support team. That being said, what is giving you the null value? `$logo`? `$results`?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee, $label_text give me null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Notice error in your code. You have used $description in your code.
Initially you have not defined it and directly using concatenation to it.

```
function label_text( $post_id = '' ) {
    $description = '';        
    while( have_rows('description', $post_id) ): the_row();
                    $description .= get_sub_field('label') . get_sub_field('text');
            endwhile;
    return $description;
}
```

Comment: This was the problem. Now it works. Thanks. I feel so stupid... :)

Comment: It happens bro :)  Welcome.